# Intermittent DatasourceNoData alerts in Managed Grafana for a Cloudwatch data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

**Summary:** I get intermittent DatasourceNoData alerts for a Cloudwatch data source in Managed Grafana, but I don't get those errors from (almost) identical alerts in Grafana hosted on an EC2 instance.

**Background**

I have a Amazon Managed Service for Grafana (AMG) workspace where I have configured a an AWS Cloudwatch data source, according to AWS documentation [Use AWS data source configuration to add CloudWatch as a data source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/grafana/latest/userguide/adding-CloudWatch-AWS-config.html). I have set up a number of alerts using my Cloudwatch data source monitoring the CPUUtilization for a number of ECS services, where the alert triggers if the CPU average for the last 2 minutes exceeds a certain number. I have similar alerts for memory utilization. The alerts evaluates every 30 seconds, with 4 minutes as a pending state. I have 14 such alerts monitoring CPU utilization and memory management for 12 services.

I also have an older Grafana service running on an EC2 instance. It has Cloudwatch as a datasource and the same alerts with the same config. The only difference is that there are fewer alerts in the old Grafana service, which only covers two services instead of twelve. The AMG workspace is meant to replace this old Grafana instance.

**Problem**

Since creating the alerts in the new AMG workspace a few weeks ago, some or all of the alerts fires with the state NoData, and then resolves within a few minutes. There does not seem to be a problem with the services that the alerts monitor. This has never happened to alerts in the old Grafana instance, even though they are connected to the same Cloudwatch data source and the alerts are similar (but fewer).

I have looked into if they exceed an AWS service quota or something similar, but since they are connected to the same AWS accout, shouldn't that result in the same error happening to the alerts in the old Grafana instance sometimes, not always the alerts in the new AMG workspace?

What could be the problem and how can I debug this without access to logs in Managed Grafana? I'm grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: It's AMG so ask your AWS support for debug/logs